# Looking for an easy way to automate clicks on a website on a Raspberry Pi Raspbian setup

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm looking for an easy way to automate clicks on a website on a Raspberry Pi 2 Raspbian setup.
Current setup: Python, get mouse coordinates and click on them.
The setup I wish: Selenium, Gecko and Python.

The problem: Selenium and Gecko are not updated for the browsers running on Raspberry Pi 2.

Therefore is the question, is there something similar like Selenium to easy click on buttons on a website and read HTML out of it which runs on Raspbian?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a python clicker library I would suggest `pyautogui`. I personally used it and it's a great library for clicking on coordinates and has image recognition. If you're able to deal with the website with only HTTP I would suggest using Requests + BeautifulSoup (bs4) for programatically interacting with the webpages.

If you want to programatically browse with a headless browser I would suggest getting PhantomJS or any of its alternatives from `https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers`.

PhantomJS uses JavaScript for scripting, there are many alternatives using for example any programming language to program the clicks (i.e. API).